# Override CSS formatting delivered by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a job section on our page which is populated by script.
I don't have access to it, so can't modify it.

Script looks like this:

```
<div id="YYYYJobListings" align="left"> 
 </div> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="//xxx.xxxxx.com/....js" > </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//xxx.xxxxx.com/....css" />

<script type="text/javascript" >
    var options = {
        CCPCode: "XxXxXxInc"
        ,ElementID: "YYYYJobListings"
        ,ShowCustomContent: false
    };

    yyyy.generateListing(options);
</script>
```

Inside script, there's one block delivered:

```
.categorySection .jobSection .jobLinkContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
```

Can i override somehow it's width, font, size etc, inside div on top, preferably...?
Is there any way to format what is delivered this way?

Comment: You could.. Just put your settings on these classes marked with `important` and it will be overridden

Answer (score 0):

In order to overwrite other styles on the page, you need add styles that are more specific.

```
body .categorySection .jobSection .jobLinkContainer {
    // Define your styles here
}
```

In the above case, I simply added the `body` tag to the selector. This will make your added styles have a higher specificity and override the styles implemented by the script.

[CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:%7E:text=Specificity%20is%20the%20means%20by,different%20sorts%20of%20CSS%20selectors.)

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a double punch with `specificity` and `!important`.

It might be overkill, but not knowing everything on the page etc.. this recommendation should overwrite with no problem.

You can try it with just `#YYYYJobListings` and not using `!important`, if that works, then you can leave out `!important`.

```
#YYYYJobListings .categorySection .jobSection .jobLinkContainer {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is unnecessary if it has a higher specificity. Avoid Important unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Jason, I added `!important` because we don't know the exact structure of everything and their CDD etc and I have ran into problems with third party providers,

Comment: The original poster provided the CSS selector. Therefore, you know the necessary structure and `!important` is unnecessary.

Comment: And where in the div i can insert that? I can't modify css or script, as both provided by third party.

Comment: @AlexanderK that goes in your own CSS stylesheet/page.